# Highcharts to populate data for pie chart using json object

Tags: highcharts

hi my json object looks like this

```
[
  {"name":"Tokyo","data":3.0},
  {"name":"NewYork","data":2.0},
  {"name":"Berlin","data":3.5},
  {"name":"London","data":1.5}
]
```

How to populate the series points to make a pie chart using highcharts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this below code. This will parse all the values and create an array called `dataArrayFinal` .

```
var d = [{"name":"Tokyo","data":3.0},{"name":"NewYork","data":2.0}, {"name":"Berlin","data":3.5},{"name":"London","data":1.5}]
var name = Array();
var data = Array();
var dataArrayFinal = Array();
for(i=0;i<d.length;i++) { 
   name[i] = d[i].name; 
   data[i] = d[i].data;  
}

for(j=0;j<name.length;j++) { 
   var temp = new Array(name[j],data[j]); 
   dataArrayFinal[j] = temp;     
}
```

And your series stuff should look like below. i.e, you should pass the array `dataArrayFinal` like below.

```
series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      name: 'Browser share',
      data: dataArrayFinal
}]
```

Comment: I am getting undefined in the name[i] = d[i].name;  if i check put alert message.

Comment: did you use the same json object you specified or any other?

Comment: I have like this [{"name":"Tokyo","data":3.0},{"name":"NewYork","data":2.0},{"name":"Berlin","data":3.5},{"name":"London","data":1.5}]

Comment: But you specified a differrent one in your question. `data":[2.0]` and so on....right? Edit your question with a proper one first. And did you use the above code as it is? Assign your JSON to variable d.

Comment: ya i have changed them in the question.. I have assigned this one to the variable d as u have suggested. But i cant get the name[i]

Answer (score 2):

Actually the only difference between your data definition and the format that Highcharts requires, is that yours has a property called "data" where Highcharts expects "y". So you just need to loop over the data and set that property. See it live at http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/uTyZk/.

```
// Original data
var data = [{
    "name": "Tokyo",
    "data": 3.0
}, {
    "name": "NewYork",
    "data": 2.0
}, {
    "name": "Berlin",
    "data": 3.5
}, {
    "name": "London",
    "data": 1.5
}];

// Highcharts requires the y option to be set
$.each(data, function (i, point) {
    point.y = point.data;
});


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },

    series: [{
        data: data
    }]

});
```