# What is equivalent C# class to generate following JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, highcharts, json.net

I want following JSON result to use in highstock pie chart.

```
[['John', 63.0163],['Depp', 19.2422],['Carla', 6.4767],['Santa', 0],['Tim', 11.2647]]
```

I tried to make `List<ChartSeries>` of below object having string and double properties

```
public class ChartSeries
{
   public string Person { get; set; }
   public double Percent { get; set; }
}
```

but using Newtonsoft.JSON it serialize and give below result which shows class *properties names* which will not be accepted by highstock pie chart.

```
[{"Person":"John", "Percent":63.0163},{"Person":"Depp", "Percent":19.2422},{"Person":"Carla", "Percent":6.4767},{"Person":"Santa", "Percent":0},{"Person":"Tim", "Percent":11.2647}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Newtonsoft is doing the right thing; that's an accurate reflection of what you're telling it to serialize. You need to transform your `List<ChartSeries>` into `List<List<object>>`, where the inner list contains a string in the first entry and a number in the second. Then serialize the result. (Or similar.)

Comment: Yes That's an accurate reflection of what I am telling. And I have no objection in that. Its just a heads up to give idea in what direction I was moving. However this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396348/highcharts-to-populate-data-for-pie-chart-using-json-object - helped me to achieve more clean and salable solution with same above C# snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try transforming your data and serializing the output.

```
internal static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Transform(this IEnumerable<ChartSeries> data)
    {
        foreach (var chartSeries in data)
        {
            var result = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
            result.Add(chartSeries.Person, chartSeries.Percent);
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tried it but serializing the dynamics collection should do the trick.